# I get "already defined" error when using `amsthm` package with `\import`

Tags: errors, import

I use `\import` command to modulize my chapters.
I also use `amsthm` package to define my own theorem environment.

When I try to compile the main (root) file, I get the following errors:

```
Command \thm already defined. ...bered,vlined]{algorithm2e}\newtheorem {thm}
Command \lem already defined. ...em {thm}{Theorem}[section]\newtheorem {lem}
Command \cor already defined. ...orem {lem}{Lemma}[section]\newtheorem {cor}
Command \dfn already defined. ...\theoremstyle {definition}\newtheorem {dfn}
Command \rem already defined. ...ion}\theoremstyle {remark}\newtheorem {rem}
```

I have to redefine them for every subfile because I want to compile and view the output for them independently.

My source files are as follows:

Root:

```
%%temp.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\LARGE} 
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,complexity,tikz,parskip,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}


\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \import{./}{import1}
    \import{./}{import2}
    

\end{document}
```

First import:

```
%!TeX root = import1


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,enumerate,euscript,tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\begin{document}
    
\subsection{Theorem}
\begin{thm}
Example theorem
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    Example proof
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Second import:

```
%!TeX root = import2


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,enumerate,euscript,tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\begin{document}
    
\subsection{Theorem}
\begin{lem}
Example lemma
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
    Example proof
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

What causes this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, you want compilable subfiles. Thus you provide full preamble in them. The error arises when compiling the main file, because there are multiple definitions with exact same `\newtheorem`. This is due to the `subpreambles=true` option you pass to `standalone`.

### First option

You can test if the different environments/macros are already defined.
For instance you coded `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]`, which defines `\beginthm` and `\endthm`. Instead, use

```
\ifdefined\beginthm\else
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\fi
```

And so on for every `newtheorem` you defined.

### Second option

Add a full preamble in your main file and remove the `standalone` option.
The drawback being you have to take care of the changes in your various preambles…

### Third option

Use the `subfiles` package. You write only one preamble in your main file, and it is shared with all the subfiles, these ones being compilable alone.

Your `main.tex` is as follow

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

% end of shared preamble
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \subfile{./import1}
    \subfile{./import2}
    
\end{document}
```

And your `import.tex` files have this structure

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
    \subsection{Theorem}
    \begin{thm}
        Example theorem
    \end{thm}
    \begin{proof}
        Example proof
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

You can have sub-import. For instance you can code the `import1.tex` as

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
    \subsection{Theorem}
    \begin{lem}
        Example lemma
    \end{lem}
    \begin{proof}
        Example proof
    \end{proof}
    \subfile{import2}
    \subfile{import3}
\end{document}
```

but your `import3.tex` has to share the preamble with the `main.tex`, not with the `import1.tex`, ie you have to use `\documentclass[main]{subfiles}` in all your subfiles.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Does this also work if I have subsubfiles? Meaning that can I import another subfile in `import1.tex`?

Comment: Sure: see the edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: For the First Option, it only worked for me if I used `\ifdefined\thm\else...` instead of `\ifdefined\beginthm\else`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to organize a project and to test partial parts of a document is using `\input` and commenting the (`input`) of parts you do not want to compile.

The big advantage is that you have  the full  preamble in a single place, so if you change a definition or add a package you do not have to alter all partial files.

Main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\LARGE} 
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,complexity,tikz,parskip,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{amsthm,enumerate,euscript,tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\input{import1c}

\input{import2c}

\end{document}
```

import1c.tex

```
\section{Theorem}
\begin{thm}
Example theorem
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    Example proof
\end{proof}
```

import2c.tex

```
\section{Theorem}
\begin{lem}
Example lemma
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
    Example proof
\end{proof}
```

Note

I changed the `\subsection` to `\section` to match the `\newtheorem` definitions thus getting proper numbering.

[image: t2]

Comment: Although this solution works like a charm, it causes a slight inconvenience by having to switch between files constantly while working.

Comment: @padawan The way I work with large documents is to put just all the tables (or figures or equations) in a single document full of inputs and debug one by one. When I am sure of the final configuration, I compile them all to verify that they have the same look (because over time the formats tend to drift). Then I enter each one in the main document in the appropriate place to check the position on the page, the floats, etc. Of course your workflow might be different. By having many different independent  files you have to edit and recompile  everything just by adding or updating a package

Answer (score 1):

There is the `subfiles` package intended for such purposes, even though you should try `\input` first as suggested in the other answer, as it is much simpler.

With the `subfiles` package, you keep the preamble in the main file and load it from the subfiles as well. For details, see the [documentation of the subfiles package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf)

```
% temp.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapternumberfont{\LARGE} 
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,complexity,tikz,parskip,subcaption}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{subfiles}%%%%% <<<<< load subfiles package last
\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

```
% import1.tex
\documentclass[temp]{subfiles}%%%% <<< Reference to the main file with the preamble
\begin{document}
\subsection{Theorem}
\begin{thm}
Example theorem
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    Example proof
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Note: I'm the maintainer of the `subfiles` package, but I'm not necessarily advocating its use.